# unable to get value from spring to view

Tags: java, spring

while leaning springMVC I am stuck in getting value from controller to view as the code is

welcome.jsp

```
<p>Greetings :</p>
    <br>
    <p>${greeting}</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Tagline :</p>
    <br>
    <p>${tagline}</p>
```

controller.java

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "greetings of the day");
        model.addAttribute("tagline", "one of best web stores");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

it is not showing any output in view nor any error

HOw to solve this? or I am missing something.

---

**Web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml as suggested by [`Reimeus`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871026/reimeus)**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.*" />
    <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

**Project Str**

[image: Project Strcture]

Still not getting output from controller, any help is appericiated

Comment: do you have a view resolver configured?

Comment: @Reimeus Please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your view resolver to match the location of your jsp page

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: changed my view as you sugessted but still not getting output

Comment: not sure what went wrong but now it is working fine and thank you